# Verb to describe fluid pouring out in portions?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb to describe fluid that pours out in portions? I mean, not a constant flow but partial. For example, *gush, pour* etc. mean a constant flow. But is there something consecutive? The only word that comes to my mind is *squirt* but it depicts a small amount of fluid. Is there a verb for a bigger portions?

Comment: Do you mean that it comes out in interrupted portions like drops of water from a dripping tap, or that the portions are of a measured quantity even if you only get one portion? A sample sentence would help.

Comment: squirt... trickle....drip....

Answer (score 5):

As a native American English speaker, I would choose the verbs below for an intermittent or portioned liquid flow.

[Dribble](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dribble) - (of a liquid) fall slowly in drops or a thin stream.

> "Rain dribbled down the window."

Things that dribble are often portioned out by *drops.*

As your question indicated a larger volume of liquid, I think perhaps "spurt" would be more appropriate.

[Spurt](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spurt) - (of a liquid) gush out in a sudden and forceful stream.

> "He cut his finger, and blood spurted over the sliced potatoes"

"Spurt" can be used in noun form as well.

> "Billy grew 40 centimeters in one growth spurt."

In my experience "spurt" is often used to communicate a one time jet of a finite amount, although it is used in other ways as well.

Comment: Like anything else in English, this depends on the speaker. For example, I used MW as a source, which defines these words differently. To me (also American), *[dribble](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dribble)* implies a small quantity/light flow, similarly to the way *drizzle* quantifies *rain.* And *[spurt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spurt)* would indicate a sudden, one-time burst of liquid. You used *drops* to define *dribble.* Personally, I'd choose *[drip](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drip?show=0&t=1381958059)* instead. Again, it's all relative though

Comment: Spurt is probably the best answer here. if the OP wants anything more specific, adjectives would probably have to be applied.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmh, I have heard the onomatopoeic word "glug" used as a verb for this:

```
The exhausted runner glugged down some water before starting the next leg of his run.
```

Comment: I hate to split hairs, but *glug* is a gurgling sound. If there's no audible sound produced, then it wouldn't fit. As you yourself point out, it's an *onomatopoeic word.* It's also colloquial (not sure if that's an issue for the asker).

Answer (score 1):

I'm British, but one that comes to mind is *gurgled*. That is when the water-flow is intermittent and noisy due to the fact that air is trying to go in the other direction.

Comment: +1 "The wine gurgled from the bottle" would be a correct use for this word?

Answer (score 1):

**[Splash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/splash)**: cause (liquid) to strike or fall on something in irregular drops.

**[Spatter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spatter)**: to scatter (a liquid) in drops or small splashes; to come forth in drops or small splashes

Also *splatter*, *sprinkle*, *sputter*.

Answer (score 0):

If I poured a heavy liquid such as detergent from a smallish aperture, so that it came out irregularly as you describe, I would say it *glooped*.

Comment: Would you use that word for something like water? That word sounds appropriate to something thick and glutinous, like porridge.

Comment: No, not water (OP did not specify the type of liquid). I like Fraser's *glug* below, that seems more appropriate for all kinds of liquid.

Comment: *[Gloop](http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Gl&last=50)* is colloquial (not sure if that matters to the OP); I'm a native speaker and I had to look it up. When I did, [glooped](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/gloop) was defined as having a sticky quality; it does **not** indicate that the substance is flowing (i.e. it's not synonymous with *drip* or *gush*). Gloop appears to be a slang variation of [glop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glop?show=0&t=1381956952). At any rate, it only fits if the substance in question is sticky.

Comment: @JohnQPublic  I did wonder how common it was, I can only say that it is what I would use, and not just for sticky liquids. Gloop-gloop-gloop is similiar to the glug-glug-glug sound which is probably more familiar to people. As a noun I would say *gloop* is the stuff that aliens leave lying around on spaceship ceilings.

Comment: @Mynamite I'm not implying that you're wrong; I'm just saying that the sources I checked--and the impression it made on my ear--did not agree with you. But *glop* is much more common than *gloop.* I had limited space, so I didn't have an opportunity to elaborate the context. Obviously if it's an informal setting, diction isn't as important. I also didn't have room to explain that colloquial speech is **not** wrong and that meanings can vary among speakers. That was my personal opinion.

Comment: @JohnQPublic  It's true I didn't check any sources, but I've never even heard of *glop* - is that US by any chance? :)

Comment: @Mynamite I'd never thought of it before, but it must be American since AmE is my native tongue.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few situations where a fluid pours out in portions, as such, I doubt very much, that there is a single word for this. There just isn't enough reason for such a word to exist alone.

The only way to obtain such a word would be to make it.
e.g. Make up "partifundam" from the french "partie" and latin "effundam".

Then use it.
"The doctors partifundamated the raw ether into shot glasses at the Christmas party." People will be so intrigued by the grand, impressive, new word, that they will feel compelled to use it at every opportunity themselves. An "I say, barkeeper, my good man, partifundamate me two double vodkas, if you please." here, an "I imbibed many a partifundamated spirit last night." there, and before you know it the word will have arrived!

Some one has to be the first to use a word for it to come into existence.
:)

Edit. Why the word does not and will not exist:

The general public simply has no use for a single word for "fluid pouring out in portions" or even "pouring out a fluid in portions"!

In general use the size of the portion is more important than the abstract portion per se, the exact fluid is of more concern than the state of being a fluid and the act of pouring out is often implicit and irrelevant!

I was trying to mock the worthlessness of a single word with such a meaning by making up such a ridiculous one and using it in mock everyday examples where the point was that it did nothing except replace "pour". This was to illustrate how it is practically useless. It is only rarely useful, in a very abstract, general sense.

Further explanation, for people who did not instantly understand the explanation above:

Take the example of "buy me a vodka".

The word "vodka" is the product, it implies a fluid and in conjunction with "a" it is also the portion! Furthermore all portions of fluids have to be implicitly poured, typically you would only say, "pour me a vodka", if making another word implicit. e.g. You make buying implicit when you say "pour" to a barkeeper. Apart from that "pour" is only used if pouring is the only action left and thus cannot be implied by any other action. e.g. "pour me a vodka" as said to a friend sitting across the table who is pouring himself a vodka from the bottle you bought.

What happens when we try and use my made up "partifundamate" in standard situations? There are few cases where it helps with anything!

"We need to partifundamate the vodka" or "I observed the machine partifundamating vodka" are example of arguably helpful, abstract cases, where the word would have some use, but how often does the average person say that, or any other sentence where the word helps simplify anything instead of acting as a pointless replacement?

Comment: You might expect, though, that there would be a term already in existence to describe what happens at soda and beer bottling plants, for example, where automatic dispensing machines fill empty bottles with liquid to a predetermined level.

Comment: That word is "bottling".

Comment: @Sven Yargs I have added into my answer why such a word has no real purpose or reason to exist.

Comment: I agree with you that _dispense_ is the most natural-sounding term for filling bottles of beer or soda or cartons of milk at a bottling/packaging plant.

Comment: I edited out the dispense example because I was trying to clarify the logic for why a single word for "fluid pouring out in portions" has no reason to exist and felt that including further examples only clouded the logic.

I don't know of a single word that would describe what happens when water gushes out of a geyser intermittently, I assume one exists in Icelandic but am currently unaware of any in English. However, whatever that word is, it is not going to be equivalent to pouring fluid out in portions.

Comment: Web pages dedicated to the Old Faithful geyser in Yellowstone National Park, refer to the output of the eruptions (variously) as _surging_, _splashing_, _jetting_, and _playing_. See the [Old Faithful](http://yellowstone.net/geysers/old-faithful/) page on Yellowstone.net.

Answer (score 0):

"gallop", after the sound glup-glup-glup. Sometimes "gallop of syrup" is used as a measure in recipes to mean you upend a jar of syrup and let it make one "glup" sound. (Do a web search on "gallop of syrup".)

Comment: [dollop](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dollop) a soft mass or blob, as of some food; lump. **a small quantity of liquid; splash, jigger, dash, etc.** 3. a measure or amount. *a dollop of wit.* – Collins